# How to find out the size of current iPhone screen to set the itemSize dynamically?

Tags: ios, collectionview

I need to make the cell in the `collectionView` as wide as the screen allows.
Apparently this should be reached by `itemSize` property.

In my example I have set the width to 400, but how can I set to to the width of the user's screen?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 9, 10);
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(400, 150);
        self.collectionView = [[NewsSummaryCollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:layout];
}
```

[Rest of the code](https://github.com/ashfurrow/AFTabledCollectionView/blob/master/AFTabledCollectionView/AFTableViewCell.m#L23)

**UPDATE:**

Still not wide enough, the next cell on right hand side can still be seen.

[image]

Comment: Where is this code? Why not something like `self.view.frame.size.width` if the code is in some view controller?

Comment: Interesting idea. Unfortunately its not inside a viewcontroller but inside a `UITableViewCell`

Comment: You have a collection view inside a table cell? Anyway, if you want it as wide as the cell, use `self.view.frame.size.width`.

Comment: Indeed. :) It might look strange but its a valid case. Please see this line of the demo: https://github.com/ashfurrow/AFTabledCollectionView/blob/master/AFTabledCollectionView/AFTableViewCell.m#L23   Hence there is no `self.view` in that class to begin with.

Comment: Oops - I meant `self.frame.size.width` when inside the cell.

Comment: It compiles, but its not as wide as required. See my update with screenshot please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Hope it helps someone else.

```
UIView *rootView = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]
                    rootViewController].view;
CGRect originalFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGRect adjustedFrame = [rootView convertRect:originalFrame fromView:nil];
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(adjustedFrame.size.width, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

The collection layout has a reference to the collection view so you should use that to set the width of the items (and thus the cells). Setting the width to screen size may be larger than the collection so you don't want to do that. Also, you can set invalidation on bounds change so the layout knows if the items need to be updated.

Comment: Sorry its hard to follow. Can you provide a snippet for clarity?

Comment: Please see here for the code. https://github.com/ashfurrow/AFTabledCollectionView/blob/master/AFTabledCollectionView/AFTableViewCell.m#L25  I'm not sure if I follow you.

Comment: Ok, if you don't have a custom layout then in `-(void)layoutSubviews
` where you update the collection view frame you can also set the item size on its layout.

Comment: I might have misled you. Please see the updated question.  As you can see the itemsize is already set there `layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(400, 150);`  So when you say you can set the item size, I know that I can. But set to what? to which width?

Comment: The width of the collection view, which is the same width as the table view cell.